# Sign in to Google account with Appium

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, appium

I am testing an Android app using Appium. The app integrates with a google account. I would like to know if it is possible to sign in to Google Account with my own credential when the app startup by Appium. The example functionality in BrowserStack:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/advanced-features/setup-google-account

Comment: Not an answer but why wouldn't the app stub this behaviour for testing purposes? Signing into an account would require network connectivity meaning possible false negatives when testing.

Comment: @Mark look at the browserstack link. It lists specific reasons why you might want to do this. Stubbing inherently means you aren't testing something. There are tradeoffs to every choice.

Comment: "Stubbing inherently means you aren't testing something" - what? stubbing means you can can control the SUT, which depends on these stubs allowing you to test behaviour in a controlled manner? Without control of the stubs behaviour is indeterminate and flaky .. hence my comment - you rely on network, you can't control the network, it might fail randomly. If you can't rely on your tests .. then there is no point to the test .. see Google post way back in 2016 about UI testing https://testing.googleblog.com/2016/05/flaky-tests-at-google-and-how-we.html?m=1